# Xcode 8.3.3 Auto Layout on Random Positioned UI Buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-autolayout

I am currently making an UI that involves multiple `UIButton`s in random positions. Please see the photos, I basically want the buttons to stay at where they are suppose to be (aka Pikachu's ear, Pikachu's cheek...) But when I change to a smaller device such as the iPhone SE, the buttons aren't at where I want.

I know that Auto Layout is probably the way out, and I tried adding leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints, but they never work out. I also tried setting suggested constraints, did not work. Some buttons were stretched after setting constraints...

So it really caused headache for me. Can anyone please help?

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltw1O.png)

UPDATE:
I have found a really easy way to achieve such layout. By unclicking default autoresizing and only select the inner constraints, the buttons can now be at where I want them to be.
[Storyboard Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53w0u.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as minimum constraints like

1.) Leading

2.) Top

3.) Height, Width

The key is to change the values either programmatically.

For example,
Suppose, the screen is 320 * 480 and the button Position is to be at (100,250),

> the ratios we get will be PositionX = 100/320 = 0.3125
>                          & PositionY = 250/480 = 0.520 then programmatically set

```
leadingConstraint.constant = 0.312 * self.view.bounds.size.width
topConstraint.constant = 0.520 * self.view.bounds.size.height
```

You need to calculate these values for each button and set them accordingly.